# Spring cloud gateway This combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, microservices

I'm working on microservices using spring cloud gateway to centralize all the requests, and then I changed to use https. Untill now everything is working greate I created my self signed certificate and used it in evey microservice and made a test of sending GET,POST,DELETE to evey micro and everything is greate, and then the problem comes in when I tried to send http requests to the micros via the spring cloud gateway it displays this `Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS.`

I generated my certificate with this command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias statement -keystore src/main/resources/statement-keystore.p12 -keypass secret -storeType PKCS12 -storepass secret -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -dname "C=MA, ST=ST, L=L, O=statement, OU=statement, CN=localhost" -ext "SAN=dns:localhost"
```

spring cloud gateway app.yml:

```
server:
    port: 8765
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-alias: statement
        key-store: classpath:statement-keystore.p12
        key-store-password: secret
        key-store-type: PKCS12
```

example:
I have one micro running on port `8081` so if I test GET request like this `https://localhost:8081/api/v1/statemnts` it returns 200 and displays the data, but if I try with spring cloud port `https://localhost:8765/api/v1/statemnts` this returns `This combination of host and port requires TLS.`

PS:

- I'm using zipkin and rabbitmq as tracing system using http.
- I uploaded my certificate to postman even that the problem occurs.
- This is happening in both postman and browser
- If any other details needed I'll add more

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem is encountered,While working with microservice architecture the solution which i used is this:

1. Enable https only on spring cloud gateway.
2. No need to enable https on microservice.

In that way you are able to call your microservices from spring cloud gateway.
I hope this solution will provide you help!!